# Build vim with a predefined list of plugins in Nix

Tags: vim, nixos, nix

So far I have been able to build vim with custom flags using `vim_configurable` nix package and setting the proper values in `~/.nixpkgs/config.nix`. For instance, building vim with lua support (which isn't the default when installing `vim` nix package), is as simple as working with the `config.vim` set:

```
pkgs : {
  vim = {
    lua = true;
  };
}
```

The main problem I am facing now is how to set up Vim with different plugins for different nix profiles. What's the proper way to achieve this? Right now I am manually installing the corresponding nix vim plugins for each profile and modifying my `~/.vimrc` after each profile switch, which is not ideal. It seems to be possible when using [NixOS](https://github.com/MarcWeber/nixpkgs/commit/613ca23e85af2d32f190f212db3020b496ee4c8f), but I haven't been able to make it work in Nix.

Any hints?

Answer (score 2):

The nixpkgs config is global, and that's the reason I personally don't like such package config like vim does.

For sure you can do something like packageOverrides with `vim1 = ...; vim2 = ...;` without using the vim config on the top-level, but rather per-package override.

Not sure I was clear enough. In other words, use `vim_configurable.override` passing flags there directly, instead of using nixpkgs global config.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [common.nix#L28](https://github.com/jagajaga/my_configs/blob/5468e44ff4c0d458e28738a5453b79c03ab2e0ea/.nixpkgs/common.nix#L28) and [common.nix#L81](https://github.com/jagajaga/my_configs/blob/5468e44ff4c0d458e28738a5453b79c03ab2e0ea/.nixpkgs/common.nix#L81). With `name` you can create several vim profiles. Like `name = vim-cpp` or `name = vim-haskell`.